# Pandas Dataframe groupby and filter by max(key)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
td = [[10,'A'],[10, 'B'],[2, 'C']]
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame(td, columns=['col1','col2'])
df.groupby('col1')
```

All, how do I get the group by the max(key). In this case 10 -> ['A','B']?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need `groupby`: `df[df.col1 == df.col1.max()].col2`

Answer (score 0):

A generalised solution is possible via `groupby` to list, then using `sort_index` and `iloc` accessor:

```
res = df.groupby('col1')['col2']\
        .apply(list)\
        .sort_index(ascending=False)

print(res.iloc[0])

['A', 'B']
```